# HTTP Response Code when POST should be used instead of GET

Tags: rest, http, express

I am building an API. Then endpoint I'm writing should be accessed using POST and not GET. But I want to respond to GETs with information about how to use the endpoint. What HTTP response code should I use when responding to the GET? I was thinking of using 405 but the MDN docs say not to use it for GET requests.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

Comment: I was also considering 303. However MDN says to use that when you want the method to be a GET instead.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303

Comment: Since the request syntax is correct, but there is nothing to GET at the requested URI, you should probably return 404.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Do you know why I shouldn't use a 405?

Comment: See section 5.1.1 in the spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 .  There is language that could be interpreted as saying that you should never return 405 for GET or HEAD.  I don't necessarily agree, but that's not important.

Comment: @MattTimmermans would you use a 405 for this situation?

Comment: I am planning to return a JSON object outlining the routes proper use.

Comment: I would not.  I would do what my clients expect and are likely to handle properly.  If you're going to return a JSON object that the client can parse and use figure out how to call the interface, then that's great!  That's REST.  You should return 200.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, ah ok. Thank  you for your time!